# code execution upon import in Python

Tags: python

When I import a module in my python file, I expect execution of the imported code to be executed when I execute the file that is importing the module.

Here is the code:

I have few simple lines in test_2.py file:

```
x = 10
y = 20

c = x-y

print c

def func1():
    return x+y
```

This is imported in another file test_2_test.py:

```
import test_2
x = test_2.func1()
print x
```

Here is the output when I execute test_2_test:

> %run "D:/Projects/Initiatives/machine
>   learning/programs/test_2_test.py" 30

I cannot figure out why "print c" statement is not executed

Comment: If you are using python 3 try `print(c)` and `print(x)`.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `pyc` file generated from import?

Comment: print x executes fine actually

Comment: I pasted both sections into an editor and when I ran `test_2_test.py` the code printed -10 and 30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code in `test_2.py` will only be executed *the first time* you `import test_2` during an interpreter session.

You're trying to `%run` this from inside IPython. You've presumably imported `test_2` at least once before since starting IPython. Therefore, there's nothing to run.

If you exit Python and, from bash/cmd, type `python test_2_test.py`, you will see the `10` and `30` both get printed.

Or, if you start up a brand new IPython session and `%run test_2_test.py`, same thing: it'll print both values. But only the first time; if you `%run` it again, from the same session, you'll only see `30`.

---

Anyway, if you want to trick Python into re-running your module, you can do so like this:

```
import sys
del sys.modules['test_2']
import test_2
```

This is *generally* a bad idea, but for the specific case of testing top-level code in a module that you're not doing anything else with… well, that case is half the reason this is [publicly documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

> This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded. This can be manipulated to force reloading of modules and other tricks. Note that removing a module from this dictionary is not the same as calling `reload()` on the corresponding module object.

---

For a slightly cleaner solution, you can tell Python to [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) the module instead of importing it:

```
reload(test2)
```

… but this doesn't do much good in your case, because you want to run `test_2_test` and have *it* do the import, you don't want to do it yourself.

---

For more details, you can read the details of how importing works, starting with [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html). But frankly, I wouldn't bother learning how pre-3.4 import works; just wait until you're ready to upgrade. The new version is much cleaner, better documented, and won't be completely obsolete knowledge in a year and a half.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the issue. I was executing the code under Canopy GUI and indeed does not execute the imported for some reason. I opened command prompt under Canopy and I get the expected results.

I will probably report this to Enthought people

Comment: I'm about 95% sure you're wrong about this. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228911/908494) before you go reporting a bug that probably doesn't exist to Enthought.

Comment: you are right. I exited Canopy and ran it fresh and it works. The command prompt works every time. Thanks a lot